# How to make CLion insert generated code.... in .cpp files

Tags: c++, clion

Generating code in CLion always result in having the methods implemented in the header files, I've always been taught that they should go in .cpp files, how can I change that behavior and is it even possible ?

Example :

In a project containing a main.cpp and a test class (test.hpp, and test.cpp).

The CMake file is as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(testClion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
                test.cpp
                test.hpp)
add_executable(testClion ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

(note that this is the default file provided by clion, I haven't changed anything)

**test.hpp**

```
#ifndef TESTCLION_TEST_HPP
#define TESTCLION_TEST_HPP

class test
{
 protected:
  int test;
};


#endif //TESTCLION_TEST_HPP
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.hpp"
```

Pressing ALT + INSERT and generating getters/setters while being in test.hpp OR test.cpp only changes the test.hpp:

**test.hpp**

```
#ifndef TESTCLION_TEST_HPP
#define TESTCLION_TEST_HPP

class test
{

 public:
  int getTest() const
  {
    return test;
  }
  void setTest(int test)
  {
    test::test = test;
  }
 protected:
  int test;
};


#endif //TESTCLION_TEST_HPP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have an actual solution for you.  I had the same problem where I could do `alt + enter` and I could only auto generate per method.  You can work around this via using `alt + insert`.  This brings up the generation menu in Clion.   From here select `generate definitions` which will bring up a menu where you can either just select all the definitions or select a select few you actually want to generate.

Clion is smart enough to know if you've *already* generated a definition so you don't have to worry about duplicate definitions here.   I've found that with QT however that certain classes have Meta Object Compiler overrides that will show up here, so I make sure not to select those when creating definitions, but for most normal use cases selecting every element in the `generate definitions` list will just generate things you've actually defined in the header.

Note you can also right click on your class name and go to `Generate...` and you will be given the same options.

EDIT:  Note if you actually want the behavior of the original author, you can select the "generate in place" option once you get to the generate definitions function selection screen

Comment: Does this generate methods in cpp files or hpp? I'm already using ALT INSERT and it generates in hpp

Comment: @QuentinSommer Definitely generates methods in cpp, doesn't matter if its getters and setters or function definitions.  What version are you using?

Comment: Well I must say I haven't used CLION for more than 1 year, I'll trust you and mark your answer as accepted for future visitors! Thanks

Comment: @QuentinSommer  to confirm I made sure that the scenario you had above did what I experienced with my own projects, and nothing changed, it would still generate properly in the source cpp files, there must have been a bug in previous versions.

Comment: Well perfect then!

Answer (score 3):

CLion actually declares the methods in the header file and defines them in the .cpp file provided it 'knows' that both files are related. I noticed that when creating new source files, you have to reload cmake (CMake toolbar > "Reload CMake Project" icon) for the IDE to take the .cpp file into account, especially if you use `file(GLOB xxx)` to list source files.

Please also check that:

- the .cpp file is listed as a source for a binary built with cmake
- it properly includes its related header
- the source and header files have the same basename

Note: CLion provides an easy way to move the method implementation to the source file if needed. Place the cursor to a method in the header file, press `Alt + Enter` and click `Move function definition to source file`.

Comment: Hi, I can't get your solution to work. I've edited my question to add more details

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was first started using CLion.  I was able to define where to implement the methods by using the Intention Actions menu (yellow globe).  I was confused by trying to use the wrong hotkey.

Currently in version 2016.1.2:

1. Place the cursor on the method.
2. Open the `Intention Actions` menu by hovering nearby and clicking the globe, or by pressing the hotkey

   - Windows Default : `alt + enter`
   - OS X Default : `option + enter`
3. Select the relevant action.

   - `Generate definition for function 'someFunction'` to add definition in the source file.
   - `Create new function 'someFunction()'` to add the definition into the header file (where implementation is already done in the source).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've noticed this way of doing it but it's very slow and you have to manually do it for each of the method to generate, it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: No worries. I couldn't find any way of bulk generation into the source.